# change text when button selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need to be able to have a series of buttons that when you select one, it assigns the address for that button to the value.  Problem is that it only does it once & I can't figure out a way to fix this.  If you run the code you will see initially I assign the `value="Seattle, WA"`, then when you click one of the buttons I want it to change it to the new value.

I added a function `ClearFields()` as I thought that would fix the problem.

```js
function AddressTextBox() {
         document.getElementById('address').value = 
         document.getElementById('address1').value;
       }
       
function ClearFields() {
         document.getElementById("address1").value = "";
         document.getElementById("address").value = "";
       }
```

```html
    <div>
       <Button onclick="AddressTextBox();" id="address1" data-toggle="modal"
          data-target="#Business-Signup" type="text" value="12080 SW Myslony 
          St., Tualatin, OR">
          Business Information - Tualatin, Or
       </button>

       <Button onclick="AddressTextBox();" id="address1" data-toggle="modal" 
          data-target="#Business-Signup" type="text" value="13009 SE Jennifer 
          St, Clackamas, OR">
          Business Information - Clakamas, Or
       </button>
    </div>

    <div class="officeaddress">
      <ul>
         <li>
           <br />
           <label class="buslabel" for="Name">Address:
              <strong><input id="address" tabindex="6" style="margin-left:
                 5px; border: none; padding: 0;" type="text"
                 class="busaddinput" placeholder="Street Address" size="25"
                 name="streetaddress" maxlength="34" value="Seattle, WA"          
                 required>
              </strong>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label class="buslabel" for="Name">City:
            <strong><input tabindex="7" style="margin-left: 32px; border:
               none; padding: 0;" type="text" class="busaddinput" 
               placeholder="City" name="city" size="20" maxlength="30"
               value="Puyallup" required></strong>
          </label>
       </li>
       <li>
         <label class="buslabel" for="Name">State:
            <strong><input type="text" tabindex="8" style="margin-left: 24px;
            border: none; padding: 0;" class="busaddinput" 
            placeholder="State" name="state" size="10" maxlength="10"
            value="WA" required></strong>
         </label>
        </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have two button elements with the same `id="address1"`.

`document.getElementById('address1').value` only returns the first element that matches the ID, so it is only retrieving the value from the first button. To retrieve the value from the second button, you would need to give the second button a unique ID like "address2", and use `document.getElementById('address2').value` to access it.

A better way to handle this may be to reference the clicked element in your AddressTextBox function. Then you don't even need to rely on ID's for your buttons, just for the field you want to set:

```js
  function AddressTextBox(element) {
     document.getElementById('address').value = 
     element.value;
  }
```

```html
<div>
   <Button onclick="AddressTextBox(this);" data-toggle="modal"
      data-target="#Business-Signup" type="text" value="12080 SW Myslony 
      St., Tualatin, OR">
      Business Information - Tualatin, Or
   </button>

   <Button onclick="AddressTextBox(this);" data-toggle="modal" 
      data-target="#Business-Signup" type="text" value="13009 SE Jennifer 
      St, Clackamas, OR">
      Business Information - Clakamas, Or
   </button>
</div>

<div class="officeaddress">
  <ul>
     <li>
       <br />
       <label class="buslabel" for="Name">Address:
          <strong><input id="address" tabindex="6" style="margin-left:
             5px; border: none; padding: 0;" type="text"
             class="busaddinput" placeholder="Street Address" size="25"
             name="streetaddress" maxlength="34" value="Seattle, WA"          
             required>
          </strong>
        </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label class="buslabel" for="Name">City:
        <strong><input tabindex="7" style="margin-left: 32px; border:
           none; padding: 0;" type="text" class="busaddinput" 
           placeholder="City" name="city" size="20" maxlength="30"
           value="Puyallup" required></strong>
      </label>
   </li>
   <li>
     <label class="buslabel" for="Name">State:
        <strong><input type="text" tabindex="8" style="margin-left: 24px;
        border: none; padding: 0;" class="busaddinput" 
        placeholder="State" name="state" size="10" maxlength="10"
        value="WA" required></strong>
     </label>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

In the example above I have included a parameter called `element` in the AddressTextBox function. I then used the `this` keyword in the onclick event of each button to call AddressTextBox() with the button element that was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it by class instead of the ID.**
*Hope this will help.*

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 for(var i=0; i<4;i++){
 var button= "<button class='btn'>Click me to hide paragraphs"+i+"</button>";
   $("body").append(button);
 }
 
 $(".btn").on('click',function(){ 
  $(".target").text($(this).text());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 

 

<p class="target">i have to chnage</p>

</body>
</html>
```